# Update database with listView

Tags: c#, sql-update, windows-mobile, listviewitem

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (listView1.Items[i].Checked)
    {
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables["EXP"].Rows[i];

        dr["MODE_PAIEMENT"] = "espece";

        dr["MNT_REG"] = dr["SOLDE_RESTANT"];

        Itemchek = dr["NUM_FAC"].ToString();

        modeP = dr["MODE_PAI"].ToString();

        mantantR = dr["MNT_REG"].ToString();

        try
        {
            updateCmd.CommandText = "update EXP set MODE_PAIE=@modeP , MNT_REG=@mantantR where   NUM_FAC=@Itemchek ";    
            updateCmd.Connection = objConn;

            updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@modeP", modeP);

            updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@mantantR", mantantR);

            updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Itemchek", Itemchek);

            da.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;
            da.Update(ds, "EXP");
        }catch....
```

It update only the first element selected , i want it update every element selected , someone have an idea  how can i do that ?

Comment: where do you close the connection? whats the value of your listview.items.count?

Comment: i close connection when i quitte the loop for() , and value of listview.items.count , number of element in listview in my case 4 .